# SUM() Over(Partition By) produces different values to expected

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I want to produce a running total by date and one other column. I have two tables(locations, sales_partner) that look like this:

```
Location:

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      created_date   |         id       |       sp_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    2018-01-01       |         34       |        12        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|

Salespartner
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       status     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      active      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I am trying to acheive a running total of the number of locations per salespartner by YYYY-MM date. Like this:

```
Salespartner
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      YYYY_MM        |         spid     |  location_count  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    2018-01-01       |         34       |        12        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|    2018-01-01       |         12       |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|    2018-01-02       |         34       |        18        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------| 
|    2018-01-02       |         12       |        6        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I know there should be a total of 740k locations in the table and can confirm with when I count(*) the following select query

```
SELECT 
    l3.id ,
    sp.sales_partner_id,
    to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM') as date            
FROM location as l3
    left join (select id as sales_partner_id,status
              from sales_partner)
              as sp on l3.sales_partner_id = sp.sales_partner_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

but when I do the following query with an over(partion by):

```
SELECT to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM') as date,
       sp.sales_partner_id,    
       sum(count(l3.id)) over (partition by sp.sales_partner_id,
                               order by to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM') 
                               rows unbounded preceding
                              ) as running_active
FROM location l3 LEFT JOIN
     sales_partner sp
     ON l3.sales_partner_id = sp.sales_partner_id
GROUP BY to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM'), sp.sales_partner_id
```

and I `sum(running_active) where date = '2019-09-01'` the resulting total is 470k not the 740k that i know to be correct. Is there something wrong with the window function i use? There are no null results in the sp.sales_partner column.

Comment: You are partitioning by the sales partner, so the count restarts for each partner.

Comment: Correct. Restarts per sales partner, but the overall total of all sales partners should sum to 740k.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little strange.  I don't see an `order by`.  Also, the subquery is unnecessary.

Is this what you intend?

```
SELECT to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM') as date,
       sp.sales_partner_id,    
       sum(count(l3.id)) over (partition by sp.sales_partner_id,
                               order by to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM') 
                               rows unbounded preceding
                              ) as running_active
FROM location l3 LEFT JOIN
     sales_partner sp
     ON l3.sales_partner_id = sp.sales_partner_id
GROUP BY to_date(l3.date_created, 'YYYY-MM'), sp.sales_partner_id
```

Comment: ah yes, that is the query I used (well i used the subquery, which i should remove), missed out the order by when typing it out. Have amended the original question.